# State/Province World Data

Tags: leaflet, gis, geojson, geo

Currently I am trying to develop a multi-layered Leaflet map using GeoJSON (for country, states/provinces) and CSV (for city data). I want it to go down all the way to city level and that requires layers of Country, State/Province, and City data. I have all the Country data I need in the format I require (GeoJSON) and I have a decent source for City data in a CSV format.

However, I only have USA, Canada, Brazil, and Australian states/provinces and I have been looking around but haven't been able to find a reliable source such as NaturalEarth (which is where I initially got my states/province data from).

Does anyone have a resource they could point me towards? Even if it is multiple, hopefully I can merge them together in mapshaper/other open source applications. I've been looking for the past month but I am new to geographic visualization so I don't know the good spots to look yet.

Thank you so much for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can try [BBBike exports](https://download.bbbike.org/osm/) of OpenStreetMap data. Probably you will have to export bit by bit as there is a size limit to what you can export.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you also OpenStreet map. Osm also uses NaturalEarth for higher layers.

But I would download their database (for test, just download a small country, then you can download continents at a time).

Then I would select the features I'm interested. In your case the boundaries (region, districts, cities/municipalities), and city/hamlets names. Then you should look at the tools they have (and what you need). My simple and stupid way would be just to import such features in a GIS database, and then use it to get data. But you may find shortcuts and use directly the data without importing in a database.

Check [OSM wiki, Downloading data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) and *Planet.osm* page, and other linked pages about tools. You may need to look the *Feature* page to known what *features* you want (just to discard most of the data).

If you want to use the tiles (pre-rendered images), you may need to read the term of services. It may be easier to download all data and render in your server, or to buy a service which offer you tiles. (all in the wiki).